# Imageflip Javascript does not flip

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, imagemap

I have this peace of Javascript code. I have an photograph on which I want to perfom an imageflip on a mouseover.
Displaying it in the browser, the original image appears. When I go with the mouse over the defined area, the cursor changes to the hand, but the image does not flip. Thus, it recognizes the defined area (the with the coordinates created polygon), but it wont flip.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<img name="juego_paramo" src=paramo_plantas_original.gif usemap="#paramo">


<map name="paramo">
<area shape="poly" coords="0,161,4,161,4,162,12,162,12,163,19,163,26,165,34,166,45,168,52,170,62,174,73,177,82,180,91,184,103,188,112,192,122,196,133,202,142,207,152,212,162,216,172,221,180,224,186,227,193,230,197,233,0,233,0,161" 
href="#" alt="helecho", onMouseOver="resaltarHelecho", onMouseOut="originalJuego">
<area shape="default" nohref>
</map>


<script>

//preload the images
original = new Image(698,233)
originale.src = "paramo_plantas_original.gif"

helechoResaltado = new Image(698,233)
helecho.src ="paramo_plantas_con_mouse_blanco.gif"

//JS function to enlarge the image
function resaltarHelecho() {
                           document.juego_paramo.src=helechoResaltado; 
                                    return true;
                                    }

function originalJuego () {
                                    document.juego_paramo.src=original;
                                    return true;
                                    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot find the mistake.
Any hints where do look for it?

Comment: sidenote: `onMouseOver` in HTML should be all lowercase: `onmouseover`

Comment: @myfunkyside Good to know, but that did not do the trick...

Comment: should it look somehow like that? http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/wfyw63c4/

Comment: by 'flip', do you actually mean flip as in [reverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipped_image) of flip colors or whatever? Or do you just mean 'change to a different image', change the `src`... to my knowledge, that not something one would describe using the word flip (might be useful if you want people to understand what you want)

Comment: @matthias_h yep. Thats it. I looked through your code and it does not seem that you changed a fair bit.  That `getElementById('juego_paramo')` is understandable for me. As well as adding the `()` behind the `mouseover` and `mouseout`. But what I do not understand is `console.log("here");`. Apart from that you changed nothing, right? Could you explain your changes? That would be nice.

Comment: @Maccaroni Glad that helped you, just added an answer for explaining the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your HTML as well as in your javascript:

```
original = new Image(698,233)
originale.src = "paramo_plantas_original.gif"
```

The name of the new Image should be the same, e.g.

```
originale = new Image(698,233)
originale.src = "paramo_plantas_original.gif"
```

Using pure javascript, changing the source of the image in your functions wouldn't work like you did, e.g. here:

```
document.juego_paramo.src=original;
```

This should be

```
document.getElementById('juego_paramo').src = originale.src;
```

(provided the original image has an id="juego_paramo" which I just added for convenience).

Your `<area>` ends with the attributes `alt="helecho", onMouseOver="resaltarHelecho", onMouseOut="originalJuego"` - this should be `alt="helecho" onMouseOver="resaltarHelecho()" onMouseOut="originalJuego()"` - no "," between the attributes, and adjusted the call for the functions for the mouse-events.

The console.log message is deleted in the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/wfyw63c4/1/) - it was just to make sure the function was called before I added the dummy images.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Well explained. I just started to learn JS and appreaciate any hints and tips. I would upvote your answere, but I cannot. Thanks a lot Matthias.